# How to extend the behavior of a Gradle task for a new task type?

Tags: groovy, gradle, task

I would like to set a few things for a few test tasks.  More specifically, I would like to add a few environment variables and a few system properties, maybe a few other things such as "dependencies" or "workingDir".   With the regular `Test` task I can do this,

```
task test1(type:Test, dependsOn:[testPrep,testPrep1]){
     workingDir testWorkingPath
     systemProperty 'property','abs'
     environment.find { it.key ==~ /(?i)PATH/ }.value += (System.properties['path.separator'] + myLibPath)
     environment.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib64:/lib64:${myLibPath}:" + environment.LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 }

task test2(type:Test, dependsOn:[testPrep]){
     workingDir testWorkingPath
     systemProperty 'property','abs'
     environment.find { it.key ==~ /(?i)PATH/ }.value += (System.properties['path.separator'] + myLibPath)
     environment.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib64:/lib64:${myLibPath}:" + environment.LD_LIBRARY_PATH
     systemPropety 'newProperty','fdsjfkd'
 }
```

It would be nice to have a new task type `MyTestType` extending the regular Test task type, where the common definition is defined.

```
task test1(type:MyTestType){
     dependsOn testPrep1
 }

task test2(type:MyTestType){
     systemPropety 'newProperty','fdsjfkd'
 }
```

What would be best way to do this?  It seems that the `execute()` method is final and cannot be extended.  I will need to do something like the `doFirst` to set those properties.  Should I add all the extra values in the constructor?  Is there any other hook I can use?  Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

In general you can extend the 'Test' task and implement your customizations

```
task test1(type:MyTestType){
}

task test2(type:MyTestType){
     systemProperty 'newProperty','fdsjfkd'
}

class MyTestType extends Test {
    public MyTestType(){
        systemProperty 'property','abs'
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can configure all tasks of type `Test` with less boilerplate:

```
// will apply to all tasks of type test. 
// regardless the task was created before this snippet or after
tasks.withType(Test) {
   systemProperty 'newProperty','fdsjfkd'   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I like the second one more.  It appears that the first approach violates one often cited principle that "do not call overridable method in constructor" although it probably does not matter much as the `systemProperty` method is quite safe.  In addition, all the context is no longer available and I have to call `getProject()` all the time if I need any property from the project.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to specify the behavior of a particular superclass setting. Say for example you want to centralize the `environment.find` block, but allow setting `myLibPath` per task like this:

```
task test1(type: MyTestType) {
}
task test2(type: MyTestType) {
  libPath = '/foo/bar'
}
```

You could do that by overriding the `configure` method:

```
class MyTestType {
  @Input def String libPath

  @Override
  public Task configure(Closure configureClosure) {
    return super.configure(configureClosure >> {
      environment.find { it.key ==~ /(?i)PATH/ }.value += (System.properties['path.separator'] + (libPath ?: myLibPath))
    })
  }
}
```

Here we use the [closure composition](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_composition) operator `>>` to combine the passed-in closure with our overridden behavior. The user-specified `configureClosure` will be run first, possibly setting the `libPath` property, and then we run the `environment.find` block after that. This can also be combined with soft defaults in the constructor, as in [Rene Groeschke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954900/833844)

Note that this particular use case might break if you configure the task more than one, since the `environment.find` statement transforms existing state instead of replacing it.

Comment: Interesting, but in my situation, the configure is invoked too early :( :(

Answer (score 1):

you can do it the following ways

task TestExt{
    Test {
       systemPropety 'newProperty','fdsjfkd'
    }
}

note: this just adds to the  configure method of Test
source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#N18D18

Comment: I fail to figure out how to do that in Kotlin DSL! How would that work?